# go to home screen in react navigation tabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am implementing Tab navigator where I am calling stack navigator inside as you can see.

*expected result*: when I go from **Schedule Ride** to **Pending**, the screen should go to the initial screen of the Ride but it remains on **Schedule Ride**.
Tabroute.js

```js
<BottomTab.Navigator>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={navigationStrings.REQUEST}
        component={RequestStackComp}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={navigationStrings.MORE}
        component={MoreStackComp}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
```

Stack.js

```js
export default function RequestStack() {
  return (
    <>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={navigationStrings.REQUEST}
        component={Request}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="startBooking"
        component={StartBooking}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="parking"
        component={Parking}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={navigationStrings.RIDE_DETAILS}
        component={RideDetails}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in bottom tab screen option

```
<BottomTab.Screen
        name={navigationStrings.REQUEST}
        component={RequestStackComp}
        options={{
          unmountOnBlur: true,
        }}
      />
```